# VB.net Print job gets cut off intermittently with all of our five printers

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing

I am currently sending print jobs to a bank of printers using the following code. It has worked for years, but over the last six months we started having an issue where the printers stops printing halfway through the page and just spit it out. This is not specific to any of the printers (we have five) and the image (.tif and .png formats) we are sending to the printer is intact when viewed in explorer.

In addition, this is repeatable. Regardless of the volume of print jobs or any other factor, if we trigger the code to resend the image again, the same thing happens when the printer cuts it off. This process actually generates the image over again, so it is not likely to be corruption or anything like that. This is written in .net 4.5.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can try?

```
    Public Sub PrintDoc(FilePath As String, Printer As String, PaperSource As Integer, Landscape As Boolean)
        PrintImage(FilePath, Printer, PaperSource, Landscape)
    End Sub


    Public Sub PrintImage(filename As String, Printer As String, PaperSource As Integer, Landscape As Boolean)

        Dim document As New PrintDocument()
        AddHandler document.PrintPage, AddressOf DocumentPrintPage

        Dim CleanedPrinter As String = Printer.Replace(vbCrLf, "").Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")

        document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = CleanedPrinter
        document.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = filename
        If Landscape = True Then
            document.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        End If
        If (document.PrinterSettings.PaperSources.Count > 0) Then
            document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = document.PrinterSettings.PaperSources(PaperSource)
        End If

        document.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0
        document.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0

        If document.PrinterSettings.IsValid Then
            Try
                document.Print()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New Exception("Error caught sending to printer", ex)
            End Try

        Else
            Throw New Exception("Printer settings invalid")
        End If



    End Sub

    Sub DocumentPrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
        Dim image As Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(e.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName)


        'Fit to page
        If CDbl(image.Width) / CDbl(image.Height) > CDbl(image.Height) / CDbl(image.Width) Then
            'Width greater than height
            e.PageSettings.Landscape = True
        End If
        Dim m As Rectangle = e.PageBounds
        If CDbl(image.Width) / CDbl(image.Height) > CDbl(m.Width) / CDbl(m.Height) Then 'Image wider
            m.Height = CInt(CDbl(image.Height) / CDbl(image.Width) * CDbl(m.Width))
        Else
            m.Width = CInt(CDbl(image.Width) / CDbl(image.Height) * CDbl(m.Height))
        End If
        Dim newRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(m.Left - 23, m.Top - 16, m.Width, m.Height)

        Try
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, newRect)
        Catch Ex As Exception
            Throw Ex
        Finally
            image.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```